# PCB microscope digital zoom vs optical zoom

Tags: pcb-assembly

I am looking for a PCB microscope and am noticing that there are many affordable digital microscopes out there that offer 1000x+ zoom.  Is this enough to see very small details on a PCB, like inspect individual pin's soldering on a fine pitch MCU?  Does anyone know if the image will be clear at this level of digital zoom?

Another subset of PCB microscopes uses optical zoom, the magnifications I typically see are much less though maybe 40x, and they are typically more expensive.  But I imagine the image is more clear, is this enough zoom though?  Both technologies offer HD video feed of sample.

Does anyone have experience examining PCBs with microscopes and can offer insight into which type of microscope is best for fine details?

Comment: Louis Rossmann likes to work at 7x - 10x: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_eQrbop-J4&t=3m30s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zoom is a relative change in apparent size, not absolute. With eye pieces and analog microscopes, the magnification is relative to human vision since the last lens is the eye and the concept has some meaning. In a digital microscope the magnification is relative to the pixels in a camera, and so has no physical meaning unless you know that size that everything is relative to. This is why a device with 10x magnification might see things that are too small for a device with 100x or the reverse. It essentially doesn't tell you anything. Instead, digital microscope are typically speced by their resolution, either width of the smallest feature they can resolve or sometimes their modulation transfer function cut off. If they're not telling you the resolution and just say 10000x magnification, probably they're not selling something very good.

When you look magnification values for analog microscopes the values are lower for two reasons. First, they actually mean something and the seller usually isn't just making up a big sounding number to impress you. Second, in microscopes with multiple objectives, it's customary to only list the magnification of the objective/tube lens. There will be further magnification (typically 10x) in the eye piece. Hence a the classic "40x" microscope objective typically gives 400x apparent magnification.

For board inspection wide field of view (meaning low magnification) is very helpful. Don't buy something that can't zoom out to see at least 1-2" wide.

Comment: They do tell you resolution but typically in megapixels.  If one had a 32MP camera with digital zoom I imagine the picture would not be blurry to the eye at a zoom equivalent to 30x optical zoom because this is so much resolution.  Now for a 5MP camera picture quality would be very bad at this magnification.

Comment: @Feynman137Number of pixels and resolution are different things. Resolution has units of distance, it tells you how small of a feature you can resolve.

Comment: So these terms aren’t interchangeable but I don’t see how pixels and resolution wouldn’t be related. Is this what you are saying?  If I increase pixels I increase resolution right?

Comment: @Feynman137 Yes, they are completely different things. A low resolution microscope can have a camera with lots of pixels. A high resolution microscope can have a camera with very few pixels. The latter is actually very common since high resolution systems typically have limited field of view and so don't need as many pixels to span the field.

Comment: hmm trying to think this through.  I was originally thinking that at 0 zoom a digital camera would have x pixels.   And as it zoomed in one would see less and less pixels.  Therefore the more pixels in the original 0x zoom the more one could zoom in and still have a clear image.  Apparently this is not true?

Comment: @Feynman137 Digital zoom is just cropping out pixels, so yes the more you start with the more you can crop out.

Answer (score 2):

"Digital zoom" is just marketing speak, and doesn't offer anything very useful.  Once the camera, microscope or whatever runs out of optical zoom, then digital zoom consists of taking a small patch of pixels out of the centre of the sensor, and expanding those up to fill the whole screen.

As you increase the digital zoom you end up with either a blocky or blurred image, that doesn't show you any more detail than the original image did.